# Refresh checkbox in ng-repeat when data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**html**

```
<li ng-repeat="col in columns">
    <span class="inputH">
         <input type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === true" checked
                ng-click="onColSelect(col.name,$event)" id="column_{{$index}}">

         <input type="checkbox" value="col.name" ng-if="col.default === false"
                ng-click="onColSelect(col.name,$event)" id="column_{{$index}}">
    </span>

    <span class="textH">{{ 'leadOpportunityHeader.' + col.name | translate }}</span>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.onColumnSelectCancel = function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        var cookieData = $cookieStore.get('selectedColumn');
        $scope.unSelectedColoumns = cookieData;

        angular.forEach($scope.columns, function (value, key) {
            var flag = false;
            for (var k = 0; k < cookieData.length; k++) {
                if (value.name == cookieData[k]) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag == false) {
                value.default = false;
                flag = true;
            }
        });
        console.log("new column", $scope.columns);
    }, 100);
};
```

What I am really trying to do, is whenever `onColumnSelectCancel()` is called, I need to refresh all the checkboxes with their check and uncheck properties.My data is changing, but checkboxes state is still not changing. If I checked a checkbox and then I call `onColumnSelectCancel()` , now the checkboxes should change according to the source **`$scope.columns`**

I have applied `$apply` also, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

If your controller code is working fine then just inject `$timeout` in your controller and change the `setTimeout(function () { })` to `$timeout(function() {})` and that should work.

So your code will be now:

```
$scope.onColumnSelectCancel = function () {

    $timeout(function () {
        var cookieData = $cookieStore.get('selectedColumn');
        $scope.unSelectedColoumns = cookieData;

        angular.forEach($scope.columns, function (value, key) {
            var flag = false;
            for (var k = 0; k < cookieData.length; k++) {
                if (value.name == cookieData[k]) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag == false) {
                value.default = false;
                flag = true;
            }
        });
        console.log("new column", $scope.columns);
    }, 100);

};
```

This is because `setTimeout` is an asynchronous execution and Angular is unaware of those changes being done inside that block so we have to tell Angular that something has changed.

`$timeout` is an Angular wrapper of `setTimeout`.

Like Anik mentioned, you can also use `$scope.$apply` which forces Angular to run the [digest cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle) which may fail at a point when the digest cycle is already in progress. So it is always safe to use `$timieout` instead.

Comment: Please provide a Stackoverflow snippet/plunkr/fiddle reproducing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is not a compnent of angularjs . So, you have to manually push update using [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Like this

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   var cookieData = $cookieStore.get('selectedColumn');
   $scope.unSelectedColoumns = cookieData;
   $scope.$apply();
 }, 100);
```

Otherwise you can use angular [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), here angular manages `$apply` internally.

Like this

```
 $timeout(function() {
   var cookieData = $cookieStore.get('selectedColumn');
   $scope.unSelectedColoumns = cookieData;
 }, 100);
```

You have to inject `$timeout` in your scope.

Comment: quick question, is `$scope.$apply` needed even using angular `$timeout`?

Comment: @Guillaume Quick Answer, is no. It's just a typo

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi $scope.$apply(); gives digest cycle error

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana did you use `$scope.$apply();` inside setInterval or $timeout ?